# Java File Folder or I/O

Tags: java

there

I am tasked with a project that requires me to read files from a folder.
Each text files .txt is associated with an .a1 .a2 files(which are known as annotations)
It contains multiples of this in an entire folders.

Is it possible to store the .txt in a a stringbuffer?

How is it possible to read the start and end offset of a files for a line?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I understod you right you want to read a file line by line and store it in memory?

Comment: Google: `java load file into stringbuffer` - first page has lots of solutions

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

- Use listFiles() to discover what's in the directory
- Use BufferedReader to read a file line by line
- StringBuilder is the newer version of StringBuilder (not synchronized).

Code

```
File dir = new File("path/to/files");
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    } else if (f.getName().endsWith(".a1")) {
        // something else
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Common I/O](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) will help to read and convert file into String and it is always recommended to use Free open source utilities instead of writing freshly